Setting up Multi-API .NET Core Infrastructure with Docker Compose and VSCode Debugging
I'm trying to set up a development environment for a relatively complex infrastructure involving multiple .NET REST APIs, a PostgreSQL database, and a reverse proxy using Docker (Compose and Dockerfiles). The goal is to configure it so that everything runs smoothly in Docker, while still allowing me to debug the .NET APIs using Visual Studio Code.
Here's my setup:

Multiple .NET APIs: Each API has its own Dockerfile, and they’re orchestrated with Docker Compose.
PostgreSQL Database: Shared among APIs, configured in Docker Compose as a service.
Reverse Proxy (YARP): Configured in one of the APIs to handle requests between the services.
VSCode Debugging: I want to use VSCode’s debug features, including breakpoints, logs, and console output, as if I were running locally.

Challenges I’m facing:

Environment Variables: I’ve configured a .env file, but the environment variables don’t seem to propagate correctly inside the containers.
Debugging: Setting up launch.json and tasks.json has been tricky. I want to attach to each API separately and also have the option to attach to all APIs at once, switching between consoles when necessary.
Logging and Console Output: I’d like logs and console output to appear directly in VSCode’s console for easier debugging.

Here’s my current setup:
Docker compose
version: '3.4'

services:
  # PostgreSQL database
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - lesgriots-network
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  # Persist database data
    restart: unless-stopped

  # Media API
  lesgriots-media-api:
    container_name: media-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfiles/Apis/Lesgriots.Media.Api.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "${MEDIA_API_PORT}:80"  # HTTP for local development
      - "${MEDIA_API_DEBUG_PORT}:5000"  # Debugging
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}
      - DB_CONNECTION_STRING=${DB_CONNECTION_STRING}
    networks:
      - lesgriots-network

  # Gateway API
  gateway-api:
    container_name: gateway-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfiles/Apis/Gateway.Api.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "${GATEWAY_API_PORT}:80"  # HTTP for local development
      - "${GATEWAY_API_DEBUG_PORT}:5000"  # Debugging
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}
      - DB_CONNECTION_STRING=${DB_CONNECTION_STRING}
    networks:
      - lesgriots-network
    depends_on:
      - postgres

networks:
  lesgriots-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Dockerfile (they are both almost the same for now)
# Stage 1: Build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Copy solution and project files as required by solution structure
COPY lesgriots.sln .
COPY Libraries/Core/ Libraries/Core/
COPY Libraries/Data/ Libraries/Data/
COPY Libraries/Services/ Libraries/Services/
COPY Apis/Lesgriots.Media.Api/ Apis/Lesgriots.Media.Api/
COPY Apis/Gateway.Api/ Apis/Gateway.Api/

# Restore dependencies using the Media-specific solution file
RUN dotnet restore lesgriots.sln

# Publish the Media API
RUN dotnet publish Apis/Lesgriots.Media.Api/Lesgriots.Media.Api.csproj -c Release -o /app --no-restore

# Stage 2: Runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

# Install necessary OS dependencies (if necessary), including curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libc6-dev \
    libgdiplus \
    libx11-dev \
    curl

# Copy the build output from the previous stage
COPY --from=build /app .

USER root

# Create the vsdbg directory
RUN mkdir -p /root/.vsdbg

# Install vsdbg, adding -v to curl for verbose output
RUN curl -v -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l /root/.vsdbg

# Set the entry point for the container
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Lesgriots.Media.Api.dll", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:80", "--inspect", "--port", "5000"]

launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Gateway API (Docker)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processName": "dotnet",
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeProgram": "docker",
                "pipeArgs": ["exec", "-i", "gateway-api", "sh", "-c"],
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "debuggerPath": "/root/.vsdbg/vsdbg",
                "quoteArgs": false
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/src": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Media API (Docker)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processName": "dotnet",
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeProgram": "docker",
                "pipeArgs": ["exec", "-i", "media-api", "sh", "-c"],
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "debuggerPath": "/root/.vsdbg/vsdbg",
                "quoteArgs": false
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/src": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to All APIs",
            "configurations": ["Attach to Gateway API (Docker)", "Attach to Media API (Docker)"],
            "preLaunchTask": "Docker Watch Mode",
            "stopAll": true
        }
    ]
}

tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Docker Watch Mode",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker-compose --env-file .env up --build",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}

I have a few other Dockerfile questions that I'd like to address after resolving this setup (for this to "work" i have to copy both apis to both container in build stage, even tho i don't need the other, and it is not set as reference other than being in the same sln). Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated!
